# XSLT filter with an index counter

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've written some XSLT that uses one XML document to filter another. Now I'd like to number my output elements using `position()`, but my filtering condition is not built in to my `<xsl:for-each>`, so `position()` gives me results with numbering gaps. How do I get rid of the gaps?

```
<xsl:variable name="Astring">
  <a><b>10</b><b>20</b><b>30</b></a>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="A" select="msxml:node-set($Astring)" />

<xsl:variable name="Bstring">
  <c><d>20</d><d>30</d></c>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="B" select="msxml:node-set($Bstring)" />

<e>
  <xsl:for-each select="$A/a/b">
    <xsl:variable name="matchvalue" select="text()" />
    <xsl:if test="count($B/c/d[text() = $matchvalue]) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:element name="f">
        <xsl:attribute name="i">
          <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="text()" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</e>
```

Here's the result:

```
<e>
  <f i="2">20</f>
  <f i="3">30</f>
</e>
```

...but I want this:

```
<e>
  <f i="1">20</f>
  <f i="2">30</f>
</e>
```

Is there any way to incorporate the above `<xsl:if>` filtering test inside the `<xsl:for-each>` `select` attribute?

Note: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336572/filter-xml-based-on-another-xml-using-xslt-1) re: filtering and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93511/counter-inside-xslfor-each-loop) re: counters, but the former doesn't number its results and the latter uses position().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why you can't include your condition inside the for-each loop?

```
<xsl:for-each select="$A/a/b[$B/c/d = .]">
```

I tested this out in Visual Studio and it works fine for this example.

This was the output:

```
<e>
  <f i="1">20</f>
  <f i="2">30</f>
</e>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I had tried to move the condition into my for-each but met frustration trying to do it this way:
$A/a/b[count($B/c/d[<some match condition here>]) > 0]

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure why people always want to use `<xsl:for-each>` when `<xsl:apply-templates>` is clearly the better alternative.

Ok, this is rhetorical. I know why this is: `<xsl:for-each>` seems to be easier. But it isn't — the following two templates replace your entire for-each construct:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <e><xsl:apply-templates select="$B/c/d[$A/a/b = .]" /></e>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d">
  <f i="{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></f>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<e>
  <f i="1">20</f>
  <f i="2">30</f>
</e>
```

Well, I cheated a bit. You can condense the `<xsl:for-each>` version to this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <e>
    <xsl:for-each select="$B/c/d[$A/a/b = .]">
      <f i="{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></f>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </e>
</xsl:template>
```

Still, it lacks the lightness of the `<xsl:apply-templates>` variant, IMHO.

Comment: People who are more used to conventional programming probably have a hard time understanding what is going on in that sample. People are simply more comfortable with loops.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I was hesitant about apply-templates, knowing I needed position() and not yet knowing how it would work in a template. I agree your revision is loads more elegant.

Comment: @Daniel Weaver: position() works exactly like in for-each: It returns the position of the current node in the context of the _selected node-set_. As soon as you see a "select=" attribute on an XSL element, a new node-set context is created and position() will work in this context.